# Calculating the variance of a random variable that depends on two other random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, variance

Suppose I have Poisson random variables $n_1$, $n_2$ with parameters $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ and then I want the look at the random variable $X\stackrel{d}=\text{Bin}(n_1+n_2,p) - n_1$. How would I calculate the variance of such a variable? I am thinking of possibly using a form of the law of total variance to get:

$$
\text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(X\mid n_1,n_2)] + \mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(X \mid n_1,n_2) \mid n_1] + \text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X\mid n_1])
$$

Is this correct? If so, how would I even calculate a conditional variance where I have two random variables, does this even make sense?

I am unsure on how I would calculate variance for a random variable where it depends itself on the random variables $n_1$ and $n_2$. I have calculated the expectation, this was straightforward.

Could I possibly split this up, using covariance, to get $\text{Var}(\text{Bin}(n_1+n_2,p)) + \text{Var}(n_1) - 2\text{Cov}(\text{Bin}(n_1+n_2,p),n_1)$?

Still the question remains to solve this covariance equation.

Comment: The conditional variance formula is the same for two variables as it is for 1 variable. Look at the proof to see why.

Comment: @Mason so I should use the first formula, and use the definition for conditional variance, then look at definition for conditional expectation for multiple conditional variables?

Comment: The formula is $Var(X) = Var(E(X \mid F)) + E(Var(X \mid F))$. Here $F$ can be any sigma algebra.

Comment: @Mason, In my case, what would F be?

Comment: Use $F = \sigma(n_1, n_2)$. Symbolically, substitute "$n_1, n_2$" for $F$ in the formula.

Comment: @Mason Ok thank you. But this still doesn't help me to calculate something like $\text{Var}(X\mid F)$ ?